# Custom fonts in xib editor of xCode 4 iOS SDK

Tags: ios, fonts, xcode4, xib

iPhone supports custom fonts set programmatically and in xib editor if implemented correctly. This i know.

My question is this though.

Is there a way to get the xib editor in xCode 4 to display the custom font in all the labels it is set to, so i can preview my view before i compile?

cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of pain the answer is simply no.

You can not display custom fonts in the nib. You can set them though which is a little help.

I hope at some point apple will fix this.